# Could you recommend an IDE to develop HTML5 canvas applications

Tags: html, html5-canvas

We're starting to develop a Web application that will have some complex functionality written in HTML5 canvas.

Please, could you recommend any good IDE (open or commercial), or a toolset to develop/debug this kind of applications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer Aptana Studio for web applications development as this offers very good support for javascript, HTML and even new libraries like coffee script. Aptana Studio's latest release in beta also has support for HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

This might not quite be what you're looking for... but you can take a look at jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

If you can't use it for major parts of your web app, you can at least put it to use as a debug tool.